# Sort list of list C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I need help sorting a list of list, by an attribute in the inner list.

```
List<List<int>> Nota = new List<List<int>>();
Nota.Add(new List<int> { 0,1,3,4});
Nota.Add(new List<int> { 0,3,3,4});
Nota.Add(new List<int> { 0,2,3,4});
```

then I wish to sort by the second element in the inner list, so the result should be

```
{ 0,1,3,4}
{ 0,2,3,4}
{ 0,3,3,4}
```

after sorting..

I tried

```
Nota.OrderByDescending(x => - x[1]);
```

but had no results

thanks for the help!

Comment: Questions that are merely requirements with no effort shown are not usually well received on Stack Overflow. Instead, show (in code) what has been attempted to far to solve the problem and what issues are currently being encountered along with a specific, answerable, objective question.

Comment: Please post your relevant code so we can see where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Your first code block does not compile. You need a list of strings, but you pass in integers.

Comment: Hint:  Look up `OrderBy` and `First`

Comment: I tried using List.Sort and List.Sortby and neither worked.
Nota.OrderByDescending(x => -convert.ToDouble( x[2]));

Comment: @JoseMariadelaTorre, can you _show us_ those attempts, and how they didn't work? Please put it into your post, not in the comments.

Comment: The first element has index 0

Comment: I mean sort the outer list, by the second element the inner list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Nota.Sort((a,b) => a[1].CompareTo(b[1]));
```

Comment: what exactly is a,b? what am I comparing?

Comment: @JoseMariadelaTorre That's 2 elements of the list.  so `a` and `b` are each one "inner list"

Comment: so, this way it compares all list not only two elements?

Comment: @JoseMariadelaTorre This sorts the "outer list" based on the 2nd item within each inner list - exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

While not the *best* method, `Nota.OrderByDescending(x => - x[1]);` would work *if you captured the output*.  Unlike `Sort`, `OrderBy` does not sort the list in-place, rather it returns an enumerator that will give you the items in the desired order.

So something like this would work:

```
Nota = Nota.OrderByDescending(x => - x[1]).ToList();
```

or, more simply

```
Nota = Nota.OrderBy(x => x[1]).ToList();
```